# How to make a mosaic path and question about names of textures

Tags: modeling, materials

I am new to blender and I was wondering how I would go about making a Stone mosaic pathway that looks something like this [image: stone mosiac pathway]. I am not sure if I can get away with using a bunch of arrays or if I would have to hand-place a bunch of the blocks seeming as there are a variety of shapes that may be hard to repeat.
Also is there a term for materials that are not super detailed? I wanted to create materials for a cartoon game I am coding in Java but I feel as though I can only find super detailed procedural textures.

Thanks!

Comment: This particular mosaic isn't very exact-- there's a lot of randomness.  For the geometric stuff, I would start with geometric solutions (like an array but maybe other things) and then randomize it.  For the rocks, I would boolean to make the cutout of the circle, then use cell fracture addon to randomly divide it, and then further randomize it.

Comment: about the "bonus question": I guess you are looking for *baked textures* or *texture baking*. The baked images are not procedural & are used in games and to speed up render time at the expense of detail when you zoom in very close.