# When having two array modifiers on an object, is it possible to two modifiers ignore each other?

Tags: modeling

[image: array modifiers working off each other]

I am a beginner to blender and want to have two array modifiers on one object, with the goal of creating a square outline (out of cubes). My issue is that two array modifiers on one object recognize the other modifier, and it leaves me with this filled in grid instead of two solid lines. Is there a workaround around this or should I simply just duplicate a singular array

Comment: Hi Sofie, would you please add an example image of what result you want? I am not sure exactly what you want to accomplish yet, but I think you want to create a frame out of cubes?

Comment: No but you can probably do it with geonodes

Comment: @CobyRandal it probably refers to this question. It contains a picture of the desired result: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/314522/107598

Answer (score 1):

Update:

easier with this:

[image]

---

it's as easy as this with geometry nodes:

[image]

first we create a grid, with 4 vertices. Then we delete the inner face of that grid. We split the edges so that we get 4 curves by mesh to curves. These curves we can give an exact amount of vertices by resample curve. Then we just instance points on that curves.

the curve to mesh and merge by distance is necessary, so that we don't get double points/cubes on the edge points.

Answer (score 0):

There are very likely better/ easier ways of doing this, but this works.

Make your array on the X axis and apply the modifier after you're satisfied with the way it appears. I used the settings as shown for the X axis in the image in your question.

Press Shift->D to duplicate the object and ***before*** pressing any other key press R -90 (that's minus 90) to rotate the duplicate to align with the Y axis:

[image]

Select both objects and press Ctrl->J to join them. In Edit mode select everything and then select Merge By Distance to remove overlapping geometry:

[image]

In Object mode press Shift->D to duplicate your new object. This time ***before*** pressing any other key, press R 180:

[image]

I'm using version 4.0.2 of Blender and it has a new snapping feature. With vertex snapping turned on and your mouse near the bottom end vertex of the new object, press G and then press B and drag the corner to the end of the Y axis so that it snaps like this:

[image]
[image]

Then join the two objects together with Ctrl->J. In Edit mode select everything and Merge By Distance. You end up with this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the two lines surrounded in red have same length, you can mirror:

[image]

Use an empty as mirror object and rotate it 45°.

Weld after that as two cubes are overlapping.

---

In order to have all the surrounding edges, you can place the empty (rotated 45°) at the center of the square and mirror on X and Y.

[image]